# Making the desired data into an object having nested objects with key and values

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a below structure of data. I need to get desired dynamic output as shown below.

I tried using a recursive function since the expected structure is as follows is recursive, but how can I make this as a key value?

Is there any better way to achieve this?

#### input data

```
let data = {
      users: [
        {
          terms: ["service|/users"],
          conditions: ["view", 'create']
        },
        {
          terms: ["service|/users-details"],
          conditions: ["view"]
        },
        {
          terms: ["service|/usersNew"],
          conditions: ["view"]
        },
        {
          terms: ["list|searchuser"],
          conditions: ["view"]
        },
        {
          terms: ["list|createuser"],
          conditions: ["view", "create"]
        },
        {
          terms: ["service|/user-contacts"],
          conditions: ["view"]
        },
        {
          terms: ["service|/user-location"],
          conditions: ["view"]
        },
        {
          terms: ["searchuserslist|button|select-button"],
          conditions: ["enable"]
        }
      ]
    };
```

#### expected output

```
{
  list: [{ searchuser: ["view"] }, { createuser: ["view", "create"] }],
  service: [{/users: ['view', 'create']}, {/users-details: ['view']}, {/usersNew: ['view']}, {/user-contacts: ['view']}, {/user-location: ['view']}]
  searchuserslist: {
    button: [{select-button: ['enable']}]
  }
}
```

#### snippet that I tried

```
   function resolvingData(data, object = {}) {
      return data.reduce((result, string) => {
        const [key, value] = string.split(/\|(.+)/);
        if (value && value.includes("|")) {
          result[key] = result[key] || {};
          resolvingData([value], result[key]);
        } else {
          result[key] = result[key] || [];
          result[key].push(value);
        }
        return result;
      }, object);
  }
```

Comment: Is `terms` always one element? There seem to be a lot of unnecessary arrays in both the input and results. I only see that the leaves of the result tree are worth being arrays; any intermediary nodes are going to be much faster and leaner with just objects. Are you sure?

Comment: yes terms is array having a single element

Comment: OK, I'm also confused as to why `list` and `service` keys in the result structure have array values, but `searchuserslist` has an object value.

Comment: because thats why we have to take the leaf of the property searchuserslist|button|select-button -> searchuserslist :{button: {select-button : ['enable']}]}. Leaf we need to take, thats y i was trying with recursive function to split "|"

Comment: OK, I'm not sure I follow your rationale. This is a very strange structure, but I can produce it on this example.

Comment: okay. the structure will be same but you should be able to create the recursive logic when "|" is available it should be nested one like searchuserslist|button|select-button. If i add one more it should be able create that nesting for example searchuserslist|homepage|button|select-button it should be searchuserslist: {homepage: {button: {select-button: ["enable"]}}}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189921/discussion-between-ggorlen-and-dileep-thomas).

Comment: got the solution will post in a while time :) thanks to everyone for your time

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work:

```
let data = {
      users: [
        {
          terms: ["service|/users"],
          conditions: ["view", 'create']
        },
        {
          terms: ["service|/users-details"],
          conditions: ["view"]
        },
        {
          terms: ["service|/usersNew"],
          conditions: ["view"]
        },
        {
          terms: ["list|searchuser"],
          conditions: ["view"]
        },
        {
          terms: ["list|createuser"],
          conditions: ["view", "create"]
        },
        {
          terms: ["service|/user-contacts"],
          conditions: ["view"]
        },
        {
          terms: ["service|/user-location"],
          conditions: ["view"]
        },
        {
          terms: ["searchuserslist|button|select-button"],
          conditions: ["enable"]
        }
      ]
    };

    var obj = {
    list: [],
    service: [],
    searchuserslist: {
    button: []
    }
    }
    var arr  = data.users;
  arr.map((element) => {
       if(element.terms[0].indexOf('list') > -1){
        var ch = element.terms[0].indexOf('|');
        var sl = element.terms[0].slice(ch+1)
       obj.list[sl] = element.conditions.map((ele) =>  ele)

      }
       if(element.terms[0].indexOf('service') > -1){
       var ch = element.terms[0].indexOf('|');
        var sl = element.terms[0].slice(ch+1)
       obj.service[sl] = element.conditions.map((ele) =>  ele)
      }
     if(element.terms[0].indexOf('searchuserslist') > -1){
     var ch = element.terms[0].indexOf('|');
        var sl = element.terms[0].slice(ch+1)
       obj.searchuserslist.button[sl] = element.conditions.map((ele) =>  ele)
      }
   })
```

Comment: the obj needs to be constructed dynamically i can't add properties like list, service, searchUsesrsList....

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Please be specific in your question then!!

Comment: in the question, i have already mentioned i am expecting an output as the below structure